# How can I pass a date to a script in Python?

Tags: python, date, parameter-passing

I have a script for deleting images older than a date.

Can I pass this date as an argument when I call to run the script?

Example: This script `delete_images.py` deletes images older than a date (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
python delete_images.py 2010-12-31
```

Script (works with a fixed date (xDate variable))

```
import os, glob, time

root = '/home/master/files/' # one specific folder
#root = 'D:\\Vacation\\*'          # or all the subfolders too
# expiration date in the format YYYY-MM-DD

### I have to pass the date from the script ###
xDate = '2010-12-31' 

print '-'*50
for folder in glob.glob(root):
    print folder
    # here .jpg image files, but could be .txt files or whatever
    for image in glob.glob(folder + '/*.jpg'):
        # retrieves the stats for the current jpeg image file
        # the tuple element at index 8 is the last-modified-date
        stats = os.stat(image)
        # put the two dates into matching format    
        lastmodDate = time.localtime(stats[8])
        expDate = time.strptime(xDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
        print image, time.strftime("%m/%d/%y", lastmodDate)
        # check if image-last-modified-date is outdated
        if  expDate > lastmodDate:
            try:
                print 'Removing', image, time.strftime("(older than %m/%d/%y)", expDate)
                os.remove(image)  # commented out for testing
            except OSError:
                print 'Could not remove', image
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The quick but crude way is to use `sys.argv`.

```
import sys
xDate = sys.argv[1]
```

A more robust, extendable way is to use the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module:

```
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('xDate')
args=parser.parse_args()
```

Then to access the user-supplied value you'd use `args.xDate` instead of `xDate`.

Using the `argparse` module you automatically get a help message for free when a user types

```
delete_images.py -h
```

It also gives a helpful error message if the user fails to supply the proper inputs.

You can also easily set up a default value for `xDate`, convert `xDate` into a `datetime.date` object, and, as they say on TV, "much, much more!".

---

I see later in you script you use

```
expDate = time.strptime(xDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

to convert the `xDate` string into a time tuple. You could do this with `argparse` so `args.xDate` is automatically a time tuple. For example,

```
import argparse
import time

def mkdate(datestr):
    return time.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%d')
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('xDate',type=mkdate)
args=parser.parse_args()
print(args.xDate)
```

when run like this:

```
% test.py 2000-1-1
```

yields

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

---

PS. Whatever method you choose to use (sys.argv or argparse), it would be a good idea to pull

```
expDate = time.strptime(xDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

outside of the `for-loop`. Since the value of `xDate` never changes, you only need to compute `expDate` once.

Answer (score 3):

Little bit more polish to unutbu's answer:

```
import argparse
import time

def mkdate(datestr):
  try:
    return time.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%d')
  except ValueError:
    raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(datestr + ' is not a proper date string')

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('xDate',type=mkdate)
args=parser.parse_args()
print(args.xDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

The command line options can be accessed via the list `sys.argv`.  So you can simply use

```
xDate = sys.argv[1]
```

(`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the current script.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use runtime arguments for this approach. Please see following link: http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_commandline.html

Comment: Please include any relevant information from the linked article.